# Javascript auto check a radio with cookie saved value

Tags: javascript

In my prestashop I have a template with input radios but when I check a radio button and then I add a voucher code, the shopping cart refreshes so selected radios becomes unchecked.

For that I store checked radio values in a cookie, and when adding the voucher code I would set a timeout for 3 seconds and auto select the radios again.

My question is how to get the input radio with that dynamic value (value stored in cookie)

```js
$(".promo-code .btn-primary").click(function() {
  if ($('input[name=discount_name]').val() != "") {
    var cvalue = $('[name^=gift_product]:checked').val();
    document.cookie = "testing=" + cvalue;
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert($(':radio[value=cvalue]'));
      $(':radio[value=cvalue]').prop('checked', true);
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ('discount_name' is the name of the radio element):

```
$('[name="discount_name"]').removeAttr('checked');
$("input[name=discount_name][value="+ cvalue +"]").prop('checked', true);

// OR
$('input:radio[value='+cvalue+']').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: the input radio name starts with "gift_product"  ; the value is correct now but it shows me an error in console ncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name^=gift_product][value=30,0]

Comment: Maybe it is wrong `^=` (put name=...), or try: `$('input:radio[value='+cvalue+']').prop('checked', true);`